# PHP Dart game calculation slow performance

Tags: php, class, permutation

I've made a class to calculate the throw outs based on a score.

For example if the score is currently 140 the class returns a array with collection of possible throw outs:

```
[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => T18
        [1] => T18
        [2] => D16
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => T18
        [1] => T16
        [2] => D19
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => T17
        [1] => T17
        [2] => D19
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 50
        [1] => 50
        [2] => D20
```

But calculating such things is pretty slow. Is there somehow I can optimize this class?

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Dartgame calculating class
 * @author Youri van den Bogert
 */

class Darts {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public static $notation_triple = 'T';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public static $notation_double = 'D';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $maxCheckout = 170;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $doubleBull = 'Bull';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $singleBull = 'Single';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $scoreSheet = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '25', '50');

    /**
     * Get a total thrown score
     * @param $score1
     * @param $score2
     * @param $score3
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getTotalScore ($score1, $score2, $score3) {
        return array(
          'dart1' => self::getScoreOfDart($score1),
          'dart2' => self::getScoreOfDart($score2),
          'dart3' => self::getScoreOfDart($score3),
          'total' => self::getScoreOfDart($score1) + self::getScoreOfDart($score2) + self::getScoreOfDart($score3)
        );
    }


    /**
     * Get score of a single dart
     * @param $score
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getScoreOfDart ($score) {

        if (is_numeric($score)) {
            return $score;
        }

        if ($score[0] == self::$notation_triple) {
            $multiplier = 3;
        } elseif ($score[0] == self::$notation_double) {
            $multiplier = 2;
        } else {
            $multiplier = 1;
        }

        $correctScore = filter_var($score, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        return ($correctScore * $multiplier);

    }

    public static function getScoreSheet () {

        return self::$scoreSheet;

    }

    public static function calculatePossibleCheckout ($currentScore) {

        // We cant checkout higher then $maxCheckout
        if ($currentScore > self::$maxCheckout || $currentScore == 1) {
            return false;
        }

        // Return bull
        if ($currentScore == 50) {
            return array(
                'dart1' => self::$doubleBull
            );
        }

        if ($currentScore == self::$maxCheckout) {
            return array(
                'dart1' => self::$notation_triple . '20',
                'dart2' => self::$notation_triple . 'T20',
                'dart3' => 'Bull'
            );
        }

        $lastScore = $currentScore;
        $lastPossibleThrow = 0;
        $checkOut = array();

        // Can current score be checked out?
        if (self::canScore($currentScore) == true) {

            return array(
                'dart1' => self::$notation_double . ($currentScore / 2)
            );

        // Current score can't be checked out - calculate what to throw
        } else {

            for ($x=60; $x >= 0; --$x) {

                if ($x <= 20 || $x == 50 || $x == 25 || ($x % 3 == 0) || ($x <= 40 && ($x % 2 == 0))) {

                    for ($xx=60; $xx >= 0; --$xx) {

                        if ($x <= 20 || $x == 50 || $x == 25 || ($x % 3 == 0) || ($x <= 40 && ($x % 2 == 0))) {

                            for ($xxx=50; $xxx > 0; $xxx = $xxx - 2) {

                                if ($xxx == 48) {
                                    $xxx = 40;
                                }

                                if (self::checkIfScoreExists($xxx) == true && self::checkIfScoreExists($xx) == true && self::checkIfScoreExists($x) == true && ($xxx + $xx + $x) == $currentScore) {

                                    $score_1 = self::getCorrectDartName($xxx);
                                    $score_2 = self::getCorrectDartName($xx);
                                    $score_3 = self::getCorrectDartName($x, true);

                                    if ($score_1[0] == 'D' || $score_2[0] == 'D' || $score_3[0] == 'D') {
                                        $nextKey = (count($checkOut)+1);
                                        if ($xxx != 0) $checkOut[$nextKey][] = $score_1;
                                        if ($xx != 0) $checkOut[$nextKey][] = $score_2;
                                        if ($x != 0) $checkOut[$nextKey][] = $score_3;

                                        usort($checkOut[$nextKey], function($a, $b) {
                                            if (is_int($a) || is_float($a)) {
                                                if (is_int($b) || is_float($b)) {
                                                    return $a - $b;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    return -1;
                                            }
                                            elseif (is_int($b) || is_float($b)) {
                                                return 1;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                return strcmp($b, $a);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return array_unique($checkOut, SORT_REGULAR);

    }

    public static function getCorrectDartName ($total, $isLast = false) {

        if ($total == 25 || $total == 50) {
            return $total;
        }

        if ($total < 20 && $isLast == false) {
            return $total;
        }

        if ($total %3 == 0) {
            return self::$notation_triple . ($total/3);
        } elseif ($total %2 == 0) {
            return self::$notation_double . ($total/2);
        }

        return $total;


    }

    /**
     * Check if score exists
     * @param $score
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function checkIfScoreExists ($score) {

        if ($score == 50 || $score == 25 || $score == 0) return true;

        $possibleScores = array_merge(range(1,20));

        foreach ($possibleScores as $posScore) {
            if ($score == self::getScoreOfDart(self::$notation_double . $posScore) || $score == self::getScoreOfDart(self::$notation_triple . $posScore) || $score == $posScore) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Check if a specific score can be thrown by one dart
     * @param $score
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function canScore ($score) {
        if ($score == 50) {
            return true;
        } elseif ($score < 40 || $score == 40) {

            if ($score % 2 == 0) {
                return true; // Score is even - so its possible to throw
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

Link to class: https://gist.github.com/YOUR1/8509498

Comment: should be posted on codereview

Comment: If this proves to be inherently expensive to calculate, consider simply creating a text file (or database table) which stores the outs for each score. As such a table would contain less than two-hundred records, it might be a more efficient way of operating than running the number cruncher every time you need an answer.

Comment: Actually I think it would be a pretty large file. When you get bellow 100 there are scores with a lot of outs. You need a fast storage and retrieval solution. In-memory or a database maybe? SQLite? memcache?

Comment: I like this question, but your code will only calculate an out-shot based on a score. Unfortunately, you can't take the player's preferred combinations into consideration! Best of luck.

Comment: Arkanon yeah that was my second guess also, just generate all te outs one time than store it in a SQL table. @PeteR This can be done if I store the outs in a database and make a relation table for the player, specific out and times thrown :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used basic permutation generation and it's super fast (0.06 seconds). It can certainly be optimized but I see no point since it's already so fast.

```
<?php

class DartUtils {

    private static $possible_points;

    public static function getPossibleThrowsForScore($score) {

        // generate all possible single throws and their score
        // I didn't want to write them all out
        // but it's certainly an option (and faster)
        self::$possible_points = array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i += 1) {
            self::$possible_points["S" . $i] = $i; // S = single
            self::$possible_points["D" . $i] = $i * 2;
            self::$possible_points["T" . $i] = $i * 3;
        }
        self::$possible_points["bull"] = 25;
        self::$possible_points["double bull"] = 50;
        // self::$possible_points["miss"] = 0;

        $throws = self::findSatisfyingThrowsForScore($score, 3, array());
        foreach ($throws as $i => $serialized_throw) {
            $throws[$i] = unserialize($serialized_throw);
        }
        return $throws;
    }

    private static function findSatisfyingThrowsForScore($score, $num_throws, $base_notation) {
        $possible_throws = array();
        foreach (self::$possible_points as $notation => $value) {
            if ($num_throws === 1) { // we've done all throws
                if ($score - $value === 0) { // we satisfied the score
                    $throw = array_merge($base_notation, array($notation));
                    sort($throw);
                    $possible_throws[] = serialize($throw);
                }
            } else {
                // so long as there are num_throws, recurse with all possible throws
                $possible_throws = array_merge($possible_throws,
                  self::findSatisfyingThrowsForScore($score - $value, $num_throws - 1, array_merge($base_notation, array($notation))));
            }
        }
        $possible_throws = array_unique($possible_throws);
        sort($possible_throws);
        return $possible_throws;
    }

}

var_dump(DartUtils::getPossibleThrowsForScore(140));
```

The output is:

```
array(21) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D10"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T20"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T20"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D13"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T18"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T20"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D13"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T19"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T19"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D15"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T20"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D16"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T16"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T20"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D16"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T17"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T19"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D16"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T18"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T18"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D18"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T18"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D19"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T14"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T20"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D19"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T15"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T19"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D19"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T16"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T18"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D19"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T17"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T17"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D20"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "D20"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "D20"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T20"
  }
  [14]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "S20"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T20"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "T20"
  }
  [15]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "T10"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T20"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [16]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "T11"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T19"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [17]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "T12"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T18"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [18]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "T13"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T17"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [19]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "T14"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T16"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
  [20]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "T15"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "T15"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "double bull"
  }
}
```

The throws I added are: 1-20 single, double or triple, bull and double bull. If there are more, or special throws you can add them.

The sort+serialization is a trick to quickly remove duplicates. For throw validation purposes it might actually be beneficial to leave the duplicates in.

You could consider accepting the notation as a string, like: `S10D20BULL` or `DBULLDBULLT20`. If you introduce the `S` for singles you can never have confusion. `D112T20` is ambigous, is it `D11S2T20` or `D1S12T20`? Strings are easier to work with so you might even gain performance. Splitting the string-notation back into it's parts is a little tricky but doable.

Note that I didn't add special checks for `>170` or `1` because the list will simply be empty. This is an optimization you could apply.

You can optionally add the *`miss`* throw with a score of `0`.

---

I don't quite understand your code, it's too complex. I think you're losing a lot of time doing sorting and converting between notation. As you can see in my solution I build the result set quickly and do the score calculation and notation generation at the same time.

---

I should also mention that I'm not too familiar with dart rules. I assumed *bull* and *double bull* but if *single bull* and *bull* is accurate feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thanks for  your solution. I modified it a little bit to save the possible outs to a DB.

Comment: By the way; you should edit self::findThrows($score - $value, $num_throws - 1, array_merge($base_notation, array($notation)))); to self::findSatisfyingThrowsForScore($score - $value, $num_throws - 1, array_merge($base_notation, array($notation))));

Answer (score 2):

- First thing I found is that your class does not return all possible throw outs for given score.
- Second is that is really slow.

But this got me interested so I made my own version of the class to solve this one. As the existing one you gave here looks a bit much complex for the problem at hand. Just wanted to make it simple, and simple should also be fast.

I made some assumptions to start with:

1. Added 'miss' shoot with 0 score (You can just comment it out if not needed).
2. Set maximum score to 170, as you did.
3. Assumed class should return all of possible throw outs.

I set property with array that holds all possible shoots and their score. And made method to return all possible throw outs for given score.

I have set up a test for my class to give you some performance numbers. I have run all score values, 1 to 170, one by one in a loop to get all possible checkout results per each.

Here are the results on my machine:

- 170 total score run (1 - 170).
- 250026 total score results checkouts.
- 4 seconds total run time.

This avg to 42.5 score results per second and avg 62506.5 checkout results per second.

So it returns all possible results, and is much faster. Hope this will be of help. If nothing else at lest maybe give you some idea how to improve your class.

```
<?php

$darts = new Darts();

$result = $darts->possibleCheckout(60); //gives 3767 results

//var_dump($result);
echo count($result) . "\n";



/**
 * PHP Dartgame calculating class
 * @author Aleksandar Popovic
 */
class Darts
{
    /**
     * All possible shoots and score per each
     * @var array
     */
    private $shoot_score = array(
        'miss' => 0,
        '1' => 1,
        '2' => 2,
        '3' => 3,
        '4' => 4,
        '5' => 5,
        '6' => 6,
        '7' => 7,
        '8' => 8,
        '9' => 9,
        '10' => 10,
        '11' => 11,
        '12' => 12,
        '13' => 13,
        '14' => 14,
        '15' => 15,
        '16' => 16,
        '17' => 17,
        '18' => 18,
        '19' => 19,
        '20' => 20,
        'D1' => 2,
        'D2' => 4,
        'D3' => 6,
        'D4' => 8,
        'D5' => 10,
        'D6' => 12,
        'D7' => 14,
        'D8' => 16,
        'D9' => 18,
        'D10' => 20,
        'D11' => 22,
        'D12' => 24,
        'D13' => 26,
        'D14' => 28,
        'D15' => 30,
        'D16' => 32,
        'D17' => 34,
        'D18' => 36,
        'D19' => 38,
        'D20' => 40,
        'T1' => 3,
        'T2' => 6,
        'T3' => 9,
        'T4' => 12,
        'T5' => 15,
        'T6' => 18,
        'T7' => 21,
        'T8' => 24,
        'T9' => 27,
        'T10' => 30,
        'T11' => 33,
        'T12' => 36,
        'T13' => 39,
        'T14' => 42,
        'T15' => 45,
        'T16' => 48,
        'T17' => 51,
        'T18' => 54,
        'T19' => 57,
        'T20' => 60,
        'Signle-Bull' => 25,
        'Double-Bull' => 50
    );

     /**
     * Maximum score
     * @var int
     */
    private $max_score = 170; // 3 x T20 is max right?


    /**
     * Return all possible checkouts for given score
     * @param int $current_score
     * @return array
     */
    public function possibleCheckout($current_score)
    {
        if ($current_score > $this->max_score || $current_score < 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $checkout = array();
        foreach ($this->shoot_score as $shoot1 => $score1)
        {
            if ($score1 > $current_score)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($this->shoot_score as $shoot2 => $score2)
            {
                if ($score1 + $score2 > $current_score)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach ($this->shoot_score as $shoot3 => $score3)
                {
                    if ($score1 + $score2 + $score3 == $current_score)
                    {
                        $checkout[] = array($shoot1, $shoot2, $shoot3);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $checkout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also if you take into consideration the fact that standard rules (the ones used at most international competitions) specify that the last shot in a checkout has to be a double you might reduce run time even more. (And OP does take that into account)

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with the rules. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an additional performance boost, you have to save the results for all possibilities in a database or file and just read the values instead of calculate them each time.

I would suggest the following structure

```
Table (checkout)

sum (int) | dart1 (int) | dart2 (int) | dart3 (int)

60 | 20 | 20 | 31
```

all darts pointing to the following table

```
Table (dart)

pk (int) | bez (varchar)

20 | 20

31 | D10
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the nature of your mistake is, because I'm not familiar with the rules of darts, but line 129 is definitely wrong:

```
if ($x <= 20 || $x == 50 || $x == 25 || ($x % 3 == 0) || ($x <= 40 && ($x % 2 == 0))) {
```

Either you want to be testing $xx, or you don't want to be re-testing the condition that already led you to that line. At the moment, the inner most loop will always be called so long as the $xx loop is. That's a performance killer. Of course, having a nested loop inside a nested loop usually is, regardless.

Another approach might be to generate a look-up table with answers for all possible scores, as suggested by Arkanon.

Comment: I'm completely baffled by his for-loops. The only thing that seems accurate is that there are 3 levels (one for each throw). My solution uses recursion to generate the 3 levels, which allows for some clever variable binding. An iterative solution (with 3 nested loops) is certainly possible.

Comment: Recursion can definitely replace 3 nested loops, but I'm not sure it would be noticeably (if at all) more efficient. Anyhow, I agree the current loops code makes no sense and requires some revision.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try.

The output is sorted lexicographically by ascending individual scores.

- If you do a foreach loop, you will get the results from move 1 to move n.
- If you access by index, you will get the moves in reverse order (1 = last move, 3 = first move).

It is very fast for 3 moves, but crumbles if you try more than that.

It is possible (theoretically) to compute the possibilities for any number of moves, though you will soon hit the script max execution time :).

The max achievable score is 180 (3x triple 20). You can waste a lot of CPU trying a higher score. It will yeld an empty result.

```
class darts {
    const DATAFILE = "darts-scores.txt"; // score names & values database
    static $score_val;  // values of scores
    static $score_name; // names of scores
    static $score_num;  // # of score values

    static $res;        // search result
    static $tries;      // for statistics

    // internal search
    static private function moves ($score, $moves, $i=0, &$list = array())
    {
        self::$tries++; // update stats

        // search from the current scores only
        for ( ; $i != self::$score_num; $i++)
        {
            $val = self::$score_val[$i];
            if ($val > $score) break;  // no need to try these ones
            if ($moves == 1) // unrolled the recursion to improve performances
            {
                if ($score == $val)
                {
                    // found another combination
                    $list[$moves] = self::$score_name[$i];
                    self::$res[] = $list;
                }
            }
            else // go down to seek the rest of the combination
            {
                $list[$moves] = self::$score_name[$i];
                self::moves ($score - $val, $moves-1, $i, $list);
            }
        }
    }

    // public search function
    static function moves_for_score ($score, $moves=3)
    {
        self::$res = array();
        self::$tries=0;
        self::moves ($score, $moves);
        return self::$res;
    }

    // turn results into a string
    static function flatten ($res)
    {
        return implode (", ",
            array_map (
                function ($e){ return "[".implode(':',$e)."]"; },
                $res));
    }

    // initialize scores table
    static function init ()
    {
        if (!file_exists (self::DATAFILE))
        {
            // you can change the names of the scores with these two lines
            $scores = array (
                "miss" =>0, 
                "bull"=>25, 
                "double bull"=>50);
            $type = array (
                1=>"S", 
                2=>"D", 
                3=>"T");

            // generate all scores
            for ($t = 1 ; $t <= 3 ; $t++)
            for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 20 ; $i++)
            {
                $scores[$type[$t].$i] = $t * $i;
            }
            asort ($scores);
            foreach ($scores as $name=>$val) $out[] = "$name:$val";
            file_put_contents (self::DATAFILE, implode ("\n", $out));
        }

        // read score file
        $in = preg_split ("/[:\n]/", file_get_contents (self::DATAFILE));
        self::$score_num = count($in)/2;
        for ($i = 0 ; $i != self::$score_num ; $i++)
        {
            self::$score_name[$i] = $in[$i*2];
            self::$score_val [$i] = (int) $in[$i*2+1];
        }
    }
}
darts::init();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// basic usage
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$score = 281;
$moves = 5;
$res = darts::moves_for_score ($score, $moves);

echo "Sequences for $score in $moves moves: "
     .darts::flatten($res)
     ."<br>";
echo "<pre>".print_r($res, true)."</pre><br>";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// stress test
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

echo "<br>Computing all possible sequences from 0 to 181...";
$start = microtime(true);
$tries = 0;
$max = 0;
for ($i = 0 ; $i <=180 ; $i++)
{
    $res = darts::moves_for_score ($i);
    $flat = darts::flatten($res);
    if (strlen ($flat) > $max) 
    { 
        $max = strlen($flat); 
        $res_max = $res; 
        $i_max = $i;
    }
    $tries += darts::$tries;
}
echo "done in ".(microtime(true)-$start)."s, $tries tries<br>";
echo "<br>Longest list of possibilities:<br>$i_max -> "
    .darts::flatten ($res_max)."<br>";
```